# Converting HTML to PNG using jQuery missing some elements

Tags: jquery, html, canvas, html2canvas

I have been trying to convert html2png but unfortuantly some of the html content mainly canvases failed to convert. Please can you help me see whats is the problem with my code. This is the link to the whole code: http://jsfiddle.net/w0vbc0wn/12/

```
$(function() { 
$("#moe").click(function() { 
    html2canvas($(".printdiv"), {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            theCanvas = canvas;
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);

            // Convert and download as image 
            Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas); 
            $("#moe").append(canvas);
            // Clean up 
            //document.body.removeChild(canvas);
        }
    });
});
```

});